# How to configure a port as filtered on server

Tags: firewalls, nmap

With nmap you can see a live system's or server's open, closed, and filtered ports.
But how do you make it show as filtered when it is currently shown as open?

Comment: With the right firewall settings this is possible. Details depend on your specific OS. But note that if a port is filtered (by the firewall) but actually open (some service is accepting data on this port) it will only be open from specific IP addresses or after some magic like port knocking etc, i.e. it is not possible to use it like any other open port.

Comment: Alrighty, that was well explained. Thanks Steffen. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nmap can detect three states for a TCP port:

- Open means "SYN" packet got a "SYN/ACK" response ("I hear you, can you hear me?")
- Closed means "SYN" packet got a "RST" response ("Firewall REJECT")
- Filtered means "SYN" packet got no response at all ("Firewall DROP")

The only way to make an open port seem filtered is to use the firewall to drop packets from the sources you want filtered, and allow packets from the sources you want to allow.  This will make the open port seem filtered to unauthorized sources.  But in order to do that, you need to determine which sources are allowed to connect and configure the firewall rules accordingly.

In other words, you can't have a port be like a "hidden SSID" in wireless, where it's secretly open but you have to know it's there.

Comment: Thank you for informations, it was very helpful

Comment: @gowenfawr, addressing _'cannot have a port be like a "hidden SSID" in wireless, where it's secretly open but you have to know it's there'_: In theory, that's what _port knocking_ would accomplish: The port is secretly open - but appears closed unless you know the knocking combination.

Answer (score 1):

With `iptables` using REJECT to deny access to a port yields a `closed` state since the host responds to the initial `SYN`.
Using `DROP` however causes the host not to respond at all yielding a `filtered` state when the port is probed.